# Block CASE expression in SQL instead of repeating across lines

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I have a game score dataset that looks like the below. I am trying to calculate new three columns that conditions on Rank using something like:

Dataset:

```
Player  Player_Rank Score_Game1 Score_Game2 Score_Game3
Tom     1   87  84  92
John    2   91  84  87
Peter   3   81  83  83
Hank    4   85  72  57
Alfred  5   60  58  54
Mike    6   79  74  64
Joe     7   49  81  62
Marc    8   70  87  47
Sean    9   73  51  69
```

New Column calculations Oracle SQL code:

```
case when Player_Rank <= 3 then Score_Game1 else . end as Score_Game1_r;
case when Player_Rank <= 3 then Score_Game2 else . end as Score_Game2_r;
case when Player_Rank <= 3 then Score_Game3 else . end as Score_Game3_r;
```

Is there a way that I just do one case statement, something like the below instead of repeating it for all columns?

```
case when Player_Rank <= 3 then
    Score_Game1 else . end as Score_Game1_r;
    Score_Game2 else . end as Score_Game2_r;
    Score_Game3 else . end as Score_Game3_r;
```

The end data would look like:

```
Player  Player_Rank Score_Game1 Score_Game2 Score_Game3 Score_Game1_r   Score_Game2_r   Score_Game3_r
Tom     1   87  84  92  87  84  92
John    2   91  84  87  91  84  87
Peter   3   81  83  83  81  83  83
Hank    4   85  72  57  .   .   .
Alfred  5   60  58  54  .   .   .
Mike    6   79  74  64  .   .   .
Joe     7   49  81  62  .   .   .
Marc    8   70  87  47  .   .   .
Sean    9   73  51  69  .   .   .
```

The reason I want such is that I want to calculate the AVG(Score) for each game and also the AVG just for players in all times top 3. Thanks.

Comment: What SQL DBMS?  Possible answers will be different based on the actual DBMS.

Answer (score 1):

You can use sub-query:

```
WITH data (Player, Player_Rank, Score_Game1, Score_Game2, Score_Game3) AS (
    SELECT    'Tom', 1, 87, 84, 92 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT   'John', 2, 91, 84, 87 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT  'Peter', 3, 81, 83, 83 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT   'Hank', 4, 85, 72, 57 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Alfred', 5, 60, 58, 54 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT   'Mike', 6, 79, 74, 64 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT    'Joe', 7, 49, 81, 62 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT   'Marc', 8, 70, 87, 47 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT   'Sean', 9, 73, 51, 69 FROM DUAL
)
SELECT
    player,
    player_rank,
    score_game1,
    score_game2,
    score_game3,
    NVL(replace_by_dot, score_game1) score_game1_r,
    NVL(replace_by_dot, score_game2) score_game2_r,
    NVL(replace_by_dot, score_game3) score_game3_r
FROM (
    SELECT
        data.*, CASE WHEN Player_Rank > 3 THEN '.' ELSE NULL END replace_by_dot
    FROM
        data)
```